# Getting image from another function - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, image-cropper, flutter-image-picker

I do have two functions and these are `selectFile()` and `uploadProduct()`. The `selectFile` contains the `Image_Picker` and `Image_Cropper`. and now I need to get the path and file from `selectFile` in my `uploadProduct()` to upload it on my Firebase Storage and Store the URL in my firestore and I do not know how to pass on it.

```
PlatformFile? pickedFile;
  UploadTask? uploadTask;
  String imagePath = "";
```

```
Future selectFile() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
          sourcePath: image!.path,
          aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 450,
          maxHeight: 450,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          aspectRatioPresets: [CropAspectRatioPreset.square],
        );
        setState(() {
          imagePath = croppedImage!.path;
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
```

```
Future uploadProduct() async {
    // i should be passing here the path
    final path = 'products/${pickedFile!.name}';
    // I should be passing here the file
    final file = File(croppedImage!.path);

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});

    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url = urlDownload.toString();
    // I haven't started the storing of the url to firestore since i can't upload the file on firestore storage.
    print(url);
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `imagePath` in the class, I suppose, you can try this:

```
Future uploadProduct() async {
    final path = 'products/${imagePath.split("/").last}';

    final file = File(imagePath);

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});

    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url = urlDownload.toString();
    print(url);
    return url;
  }
```

#### split and .last explanation

So if `imageData` is something like `app/name/image.jpg`

Calling `split("/")` on `imageData` would give a list like:

`['app', 'name', 'image.jpg']`

You can see it as "separate by"

Then, `.last` picks the last item in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked well. care to explain what is the split and the ```.last``` does? would appreciate your response.

Comment: Hi @flutternewbiee, I updated my answer, please check.